# Need to Fetch If assigned PermissionSet to user have specific permission

Tags: apex, soql, permissions, permission-sets

**Requirement**-I need to sent true or false flag based on permissions assigned to user Permission sets.
Suppose one user is having 5 permissions assigned to him/her ,I need to check`(PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub=true or PermissionsManageNetworks=true or PermissionsPackaging2=true)` and if any permission is having any one of the permission i need to sent true flag else false
i am not able to build a code to address this

> SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Name,AssigneeId  FROM PermissionSetAssignment
>   WHERE Assignee.Username='testUser@ttest.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the relationship query and query on `PermissionSet` Object which has all these permissions mentioned. You can query on `PermissionSetAssignment` and traverse to `PermissionSet` object and get the required results.

Your `SOQL` query should be something like below

```
SELECT AssigneeId,PermissionSetId,PermissionSet.PermissionsManageNetworks,
        PermissionSet.PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub,
        PermissionSet.PermissionsPackaging2 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE Assignee.Username='testUser@ttest.com'
```

This below query will give you the records from Profile and PermissionSet

```
SELECT AssigneeId,
        permissionset.name, 
        PermissionSetId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE Assignee.FederationIdentifier='d866070' 
    and (PermissionSet.PermissionsManageNetworks=true or 
        PermissionSet.PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub=true or 
        PermissionSet.PermissionsPackaging2=true)
```

There is a field called `IsOwnedByProfile` on `PermissionSet` which mention that the permission is provided at `Profile` level or `PermissionSet` level. Adding a additional check on the above query can get you the records only from `Profile` or only from `PermissionSet`. If you want only records of PermissionSet, get the records where `IsOwnedByProfile` is `false`, so your query would be

```
SELECT AssigneeId,
        permissionset.name, 
        PermissionSetId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE Assignee.FederationIdentifier='d866070' 
    and (PermissionSet.PermissionsManageNetworks=true or 
        PermissionSet.PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub=true or 
        PermissionSet.PermissionsPackaging2=true) 
    and PermissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = false
```

You can refer the documentation on [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm) for further information.

Comment: Thaks for solution,based on above query I have prepared below query.......SELECT AssigneeId,permissionset.name,PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE Assignee.FederationIdentifier='d866070' and (PermissionSet.PermissionsManageNetworks=true or PermissionSet.PermissionsConnectOrgToEnvironmentHub=true or PermissionSet.PermissionsPackaging2=true)

Comment: But i am geeting some system permissions on this..How to avoid system permission Set to check

Comment: Those are not system permissions, but those are the records which are owned by `Profile`, you can filter them using `IsOwnedByProfile` on `PermissionSet` object, Updated the answer with the same. That should help you.